# Count with several conditions - oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, count

Im trying to do a count of particular transactions that have specific conditions and cant seem to make it work.Also in the query I select other columns from other tables

for example:
Want to select all transactions

- where transactions.ID_1 = transactions.ID_2,
- where transaction.dir = "outbound"  and transactions.status in ("completed", "processing")
  and do a count on this. like:

  ```
    select 
    m.ID
   ,m.Number
   ,t.Status
   ,(column that counts of all transactions with the conditions mentioned above)
   ,p.label

   from module m 
   inner join transactions t on t.ID_1 = m.ID
   inner join process p on p.ID = m.ID`
  ```

Tried with sum and when and if statement but doesn't work

Comment: This is not clear. What tables are you dealing with? You mention a transaction table plus tables a, b, and c. Please tell us what these tables represent. From which table do you want to show columns/rows? Please show sample data for the tables and the result you are expecting for this sample data.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for `GROUP BY`?

Comment: ok I adjusted my question, hope its more clear now :)

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Answer (score 0):

I consider this is a simple count you can use the next script:

```
SELECT COUNT(transactions.ID_1) 
FROM YOUR_TABLE 
WHERE transactions.ID_1 = transactions.ID_2
AND transaction.dir = "xxx" 
AND transactions.status in ("a", "b")
```

Comment: Thank you! but I need to select multiple columns in this query. So I guess i need all conditions only for this count and not on all table.

Comment: so for example select column_a, column_b, then the count column from table a inner join table b on .......   inner join table_c on .......

Comment: Oh, I get it, but in this case you need to know at least one more condition to do this join successfully, because otherwise the column you join will always have the same value for each row

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to `GROUP BY`. Use a `CASE`*expression* to do *conditional aggregation*.

```
select 
  m.ID
 ,m.Number
 ,t.Status
 ,SUM(case when transaction.dir = 'outbound'
            and transactions.status in ('completed', 'processing') then 1
           else 0
      end)
 ,p.label

from module m 
 inner join transactions t on t.ID_1 = m.ID
 inner join process p on p.ID = m.ID
group by m.ID
 ,m.Number
 ,t.Status
  p.label
```